# How to fix django appendslash runtime error?

Tags: django

So basically I have a pdf.html that is called upon by my view.

My form in the pdf.html is as follows:

```
<form action="{% url "soapdf:submitemail" %}" method="post">
    {%  csrf_token %}
    {{ emailform }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The corresponding function on views.py looks like this:

```
def submitemail(request):
    if(request.method=='POST'):

     return HttpResponse(request.POST['text_email'])
    else:
        return HttpResponse("false")
```

and my urls.py looks as follows:
app_name = 'soapdf' # use this to namespace the application so that you can use the url tagging scheme

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('',views.get_pdf,name='get_pdf'),
    path('submitemail/',views.submitemail,name='submitemail')
]
```

However on clicking the submit button I get the following error. My redirect has the slash but still doesnt work.

```
RuntimeError at /submitemail
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to localhost:8000/submitemail/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this runtimeerror

Comment: If you do want to avoid ending URLs with slash. You can set `APPEND_SLASH=False` in settings.py

Comment: I want the url to end with a slash. I am sending it like that. Its a post request that should end with a slash.

Comment: one solution is to put `{% url "soapdf:submitemail" %}/` (note the trailing slash after the url tag).

Comment: http://localhost:8000/get_pdfsubmitemail/// this is the url that gets generated when i add that trailing url.

Answer (score 1):

Add trailing slash  in your main `urls.py` where you have included this get_pdf urls

I think it's like

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('get_pdf',include('yourapp.urls')),

]
```

and it will be

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('get_pdf/',include('yourapp.urls')),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

If SEO is not important, you can serve both with and without slash. In Django 3.X:

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [ 
    re_path('^/?$',views.get_pdf,name='get_pdf'),
    re_path('^submitemail/?$',views.submitemail,name='submitemail')
]
```

But if SEO is important, it is better to add slash automatically by Nginx or something else.